# How to covert Matlab ode45 function to C++

Tags: c++, matlab

In Matlab, I used the ode45 function to solve an equation in the following code where `abc` is a float number that will change during runtime:

`[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x) -x + abc, [0 15], -1);`

I am trying to convert this into C++ code so that I would get the same result, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to do this. Which method in C++ should I use, and how could I get the same result in C++?

Comment: There is no such method built into the C++ language.  You need something like a linear algebra library.  If you're actually trying to invoke the MATLAB function itself from C++, then please update your question to indicate this intention.

Comment: This function seems to implement the Runge-Kutta  algorithm in its simplest form. Wikipedia for example provide the simple related equations